# How to add facebook authentication to my react app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using express as backend. I implemented facebook authentication at the backend.

```
router.get('/login/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook',{scope:['email']}));

router.get('/login/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook',{
        successRedirect : '/home',
        failureRedirect:'/'
})
```

);

Now I want to call this through my react app, so that when the user lands up at home page, first he should be authenticated by facebook then only he can see homepage. How can I do this ?

I tried using react-router, but I can't understand how to call backend using react-router.
I also fetched /login/facebook using fetch command :

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch("127.0.0.1:3001/login/facebook");
```

But it gave me CORS error.

My react app is at 127.0.0.1:3000 and express server at 127.0.0.1:3001.

Answer (score 1):

If this issue is only in dev mode, then Daniel's answer is correct.

In any case, I recommend to avoid calling the :3001 api directly from the :3000 app. Here's what I would do.

I will edit the fetch call as follows,

```
componentDidMount(){
    fetch("/login/facebook");
}
```

This call will be received by the backend which serves the react application. 
Now there are **three** cases,

**Case 1**: Your file serving app will have a proxy method which can forward requests to an API. For example read it [here](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#proxying-api-requests-in-development)

**Case 2** This is my **Recommended** approach. I would simply write the authentication logic in the :3000 server and only use the :3001 API for handling business logic of the app.

**Case 3**: If you have a backend app (:3000), say written using expressJs, you can forward the request to the :3001 API. Here is a sample code for that,

```
client.send({
    method: req.method,
    path: req.url,
    data: req.body,
    params: req.params
}).then( (response) => {
    // Something
}).catch( (err) => {
    // Handle error
});
```

Here the client is a module which uses the `request` module to make HTTP calls.
You can implement the above call as an express middleware to use it for all HTTP calls.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options:

If you are using webpack dev server, you can set up a proxy to your api. See [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy)

You can temporary disable cors validation during development. See [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#proxy)